# Can the words highly & unlikely be used together?

Tags: word-usage

I was wonder if highly can be used before the word unlikely. Making the sentence look like,

> It's highly unlikely that this would happen.

Comment: Not only can you do it, it's very commonly done too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is fine. "It's highly unlikely that it will snow today." 
(And be sure to add an apostrophe for the "It is" contraction.)

Comment: You obviously don't live in Minnesota.